# Pointer to Reference or Reference to Pointer

Tags: c++

I just asked myself what is the proper syntax of *References to Pointers* and/or *Pointers to References*. Also is there any difference between them?

```
int*& x1;
int&* x2;
```

EDIT:

```
int*& valid;
int&* wrong;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One makes sense, the other doesn't. You can only form pointer types based on object and function types, or on `void`. Since a reference is none of those, there is no type "pointer to reference".

Here's another perspective: A pointer stores the address of an object or function. A reference variable isn't an object, though, it merely *refers* to an object. You don't take the address of a variable, but the address of an *object*.